# ios swift parse: Having general issues with deep queries and their result data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am still having problems understanding the correct way of handling deeper pointer structure in parse.

Example:

**Card** has pointer to **CardSet**

**CardSet** has pointers to **Lesson** and **User**

Lets say, I want to have all CardSets including

- Lesson.name
- Count of Cards for each CardSet

Can I query all this in just one query?
And have the data available without any additional  `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` queries?

I know that I can get the Lesson with

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.includeKey("lesson")
```

But that gives me only the lesson object, I can not access any data (like the col "name") from this class unless I use `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` what takes another query and of course more time to load.

What can I do to have all queried data

***including all pointers columns***

in order to pin this data to the local datastore with

`PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)`

And not to forget, how can I query the number of cards related to the CardSet?

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend subclassing in Parse, it makes relationships between tables (pointers etc) clearer.
How to subclass the PFObjects you can explore [this guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS) on parse

**How to query the number of cards in CardSet**

You need the CardSet from which you want the cards. (PFObject or subclassed PFObject).
Then just do this:

```
var query = PFQuery(classname: "cards")
query.whereKey("CardSet", equalTo: yourCardSetObject)
//Synchronously
query.findObjects().count
//Asynchronously
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (objects, error) in
      if error != nil {
           println(error.localizedDescription)
           return
      }
      objects.count             
 })
```

**How to get the name of the lesson**

As I said, it's recommended to subclass the PFObjects because you need to cast the objects what isn't really funny to debug and is horrible code.
I did it that way:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "CardSet")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.includeKey("lesson")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
     (objects, error) in
     if error != nil {
         println(error.localizedDescription)
         return
     }
     for object in objects as? [PFObject] {
         var lesson = object["lesson"] as PFObject
         println(lesson["name"])
     }
})
```